# undefined reference to KDL::Rotation::Quaternion

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, kdl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using orocos toolchain 2.9, ros kinetic, ubunt u16.

```
CMakeFiles/localisation-component.dir/src/localisation-component.cpp.o: In function `Localisation::updateHook()':
localisation-component.cpp:(.text._ZN12Localisation10updateHookEv[_ZN12Localisation10updateHookEv]+0xd3): undefined reference to `KDL::Rotation::Quaternion(double, double, double, double)'
localisation-component.cpp:(.text._ZN12Localisation10updateHookEv[_ZN12Localisation10updateHookEv]+0xe6): undefined reference to `KDL::epsilon'
localisation-component.cpp:(.text._ZN12Localisation10updateHookEv[_ZN12Localisation10updateHookEv]+0x10b): undefined reference to `KDL::Rotation::GetRotAngle(KDL::Vector&, double) const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
youbot-controller/CMakeFiles/localisation-component.dir/build.make:133: recipe for target '/home/robot/youbot_catkin_ws/devel/lib/orocos/gnulinux/youbot-controller/liblocalisation-component-gnulinux.so' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/robot/youbot_catkin_ws/devel/lib/orocos/gnulinux/youbot-controller/liblocalisation-component-gnulinux.so] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1273: recipe for target 'youbot-controller/CMakeFiles/localisation-component.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [youbot-controller/CMakeFiles/localisation-component.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

My CmakeLists.txt file is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(youbot-controller)

### ROS Dependencies ###
# Find the RTT-ROS package (this transitively includes the Orocos CMake macros)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  rtt_ros

  rtt_tf
  # ADDITIONAL ROS PACKAGES
  )
  
find_package(orocos_kdl)
find_package(kdl_parser)

include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

### Orocos Dependencies ###
# Note that orocos_use_package() does not need to be called for any dependency
# listed in the package.xml file

include_directories(${USE_OROCOS_INCLUDE_DIRS})

### Orocos Targets ###

orocos_component(localisation-component src/localisation-component.cpp)
target_link_libraries(localisation-component ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${USE_OROCOS_LIBRARIES})

# orocos_library(my_library src/my_library.cpp)
# target_link_libraries(my_library ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${USE_OROCOS_LIBRARIES})

# orocos_service(my_service src/my_service.cpp)
# target_link_libraries(my_service ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${USE_OROCOS_LIBRARIES})

# orocos_plugin(my_plugin src/my_plugin.cpp)

# target_link_libraries(my_plugin ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${USE_OROCOS_LIBRARIES})

# orocos_typekit(my_typekit src/my_typekit.cpp)
# target_link_libraries(my_typekit ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${USE_OROCOS_LIBRARIES})

### Orocos Package Exports and Install Targets ###

# Generate install targets for header files

orocos_install_headers(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME})

# Export package information (replaces catkin_package() macro) 
orocos_generate_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  DEPENDS rtt_ros
  )
```

the src file is:

```
#ifndef OROCOS_LOCALISATION_COMPONENT_HPP
#define OROCOS_LOCALISATION_COMPONENT_HPP

#include <rtt/RTT.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <geometry_msgs/Pose2D.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/TransformStamped.h>
#include <kdl/frames.hpp>

class Localisation
    : public RTT::TaskContext
{
    geometry_msgs::TransformStamped tfs;
    RTT::OutputPort<geometry_msgs::Pose2D> outpose;
 public:
    Localisation(std::string const& name)
        : TaskContext(name, PreOperational)
    {
        addPort("pose", outpose).doc("Contains latest Youbot Pose.");
    }

    bool configureHook() {
        /** Check in here that we can call rtt_tf */
        return false;
    }

    void updateHook() {
        try {
            /* tfs = ...call rtt_tf and query the transform /odom to /base_footprint ... ; */
        } catch (...) {
            return;
        }
        geometry_msgs::Pose2D pose;
        pose.x = tfs.transform.translation.x;
        pose.y = tfs.transform.translation.y;
        geometry_msgs::Quaternion qu = tfs.transform.rotation;
        KDL::Rotation rot = KDL::Rotation::Quaternion(qu.x, qu.y, qu.z, qu.w);
        KDL::Vector v;
        pose.theta = rot.GetRotAngle(v);
        outpose.write(pose);
    }
};

#endif
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285133/undefined-reference-to-kdl::rotation::quaternion/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2018-03-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-12**:
So where do you link against `kdl_parser` libraries? Just `find_package(..)`ing that package is not enough.

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2018-03-12**:
i tried like that also but still the same error. something problem with api version mismatch?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-13**:\

> i tried like that also

you tried what? As always: *show* what you did.

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2018-03-13**:
i've edited above question in CmakeLists.txt file. by adding
find_package(orocos_kdl)
find_package(kdl_parser)
and
target_link_libraries(localisation-component ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${USE_OROCOS_LIBRARIES})

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-13**:
I'm not too familiar with what `${USE_OROCOS_LIBRARIES}` does exactly, but unless it automatically pulls in the libraries of `kdl_parser` and `orocos_kdl`, I would expect to still see linker errors.

Note also that this doesn't seem like a ROS question. At best one to ask of the OROCOS devs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `orocos_kdl_LIBRARIES` are not picked up by catkin or orocos, so they are not part of `${catkin_LIBRARIES}` or `${USE_OROCOS_LIBRARIES}`.  you need to add them to your `target_link_libraries` statement:

`target_link_libraries(localisation-component ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${USE_OROCOS_LIBRARIES} ${orocos_kdl_LIBRARIES})`,

your probably should do something similar for the include directories:

`include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${orocos_kdl_INCLUDE_DIRS}`

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Smits](https://answers.ros.org/users/350/ruben-smits/) with karma: 543 on 2018-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3